# Move cursor escape sequence

Tags: c, terminal, ansi-escape

I am trying to move the cursor in a terminal program using escape sequences. In the below C program, it seems like the first three commands are successful (clear screen, move cursor home, print some reference text), however the last command where I try to move the cursor to an arbitrary position fails (2,2) instead moves the cursor to the beginning of the fourth line and also clears the fourth line. What am I doing wrong?

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
  printf("\x1b[2J"); // clear screen
  printf("\033[H"); // move cursor home
  printf("1111\n2222\n3333\n4444"); // add some text to screen for reference
  printf("\033[2;2H"); // move cursor to 2,2
  while (1); // keep program running
}
```

Comment: Each type of terminal can have its own escape sequences.  A more portable way of controlling a terminal is with the curses library (see `man curses` or `man ncurses`).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to call `fflush`:

```
printf("\033[2;2H"); // move cursor to 2,2
fflush(stdout);
while (1); // keep program running
```

Notice that `while (1);` is not the correct way to keep the program running, an endless loop without a `sleep` will consume 100% of the CPU, instead:

```
while (1) sleep(1); // #include <unistd.h> for sleep()
```

or better yet:

```
getchar();
```